# Replacing NA value in dataframe by first or last value of other columns within group

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na

I have the following dataframe:

```
Group<-c(A,A,A,B,B,B)
Dates<-(c("01-01-2000","02-01-2000","03-01-2000","01-05-2020","02-05-2020","03-05-2020"))
Departure<-c("01-01-2000","01-01-2000","01-01-2000",NA,NA,NA)
Arrival<-c(NA,NA,NA,"03-02-2020","03-02-2020","03-02-2020")
Dates<-data.frame(Dates,Departure,Arrival)
Dates

 Group  Dates      Departure    Arrival
     1  01-01-2000 02-01-2000       <NA>
     1  02-01-2000 02-01-2000       <NA>
     1  03-01-2000 02-01-2000       <NA>
     2  01-05-2000       <NA> 31-12-2020
     2  02-05-2000       <NA> 31-12-2020
     2  03-05-2000       <NA> 31-12-2020
```

Here is what I want to do:

- For the "Departure" column: if the value is NOT NA, leave as is. If the value is NA, then replace with the FIRST value of the "Dates" column within each group.
- For the "Arrival" column: if the value is NOT NA, leave as is. If the value is NA, then replace with the LAST value of the "Dates" column within each group.

I would then obtain the following dataframe:

```
 Group  Dates      Departure    Arrival
     1  01-01-2000 02-01-2000   03-01-2000
     1  02-01-2000 02-01-2000   03-01-2000
     1  03-01-2000 02-01-2000   03-01-2000
     2  01-05-2000 01-05-2000   31-12-2020
     2  02-05-2000 01-05-2000   31-12-2020
     2  03-05-2000 01-05-2000   31-12-2020
```

I'm thinking of using a combination of if else and group_by from dplyr, but beyond that I'm stuck. Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `replace_na` (from `tidyr`) after grouping by 'Group' to replace the `NA` elements with either the `first` or `last` values of 'Dates' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Group) %>% 
   mutate(Departure = replace_na(Departure, first(Dates)), 
          Arrival = replace_na(Arrival, last(Dates))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

NOTE: Here we assume that 'Dates' are already `order`ed.  If not, take the `min` and `max` after converting to `Date` class

```
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(across(-Group, dmy)) %>%
   group_by(Group) %>% 
   mutate(Departure = replace_na(Departure, min(Dates)), 
          Arrival = replace_na(Arrival, max(Dates))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP has asked to replace `NA` values in a data.frame.

One of `data.table`'s strong points is the ability to *update by reference*, i.e., to *replace values without copying* the whole dataset.

In addition, `data.table`'s `fcoalesce()` function is used together with `Map()`.

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("Departure", "Arrival")
setDT(df_Dates)[, (cols) := Map(fcoalesce, .SD, Dates[c(1L, .N)]), .SDcols = cols, by = Group]
df_Dates
```

> ```
>    Group      Dates  Departure    Arrival
> 1:     A 01-01-2000 01-01-2000 03-01-2000
> 2:     A 02-01-2000 01-01-2000 03-01-2000
> 3:     A 03-01-2000 01-01-2000 03-01-2000
> 4:     B 01-05-2020 01-05-2020 03-02-2020
> 5:     B 02-05-2020 01-05-2020 03-02-2020
> 6:     B 03-05-2020 01-05-2020 03-02-2020
> ```

`Map()` picks the first value of `Dates` in each groups for the first column `Departures` and the last value `Dates[.N]` for the second column `Arrival` when calling `fcoalesce()`.

Please, note that the original dataset has been changed in place which can be verified by calling `address()` before and after.

Using `min(Dates)` and `max(Dates)` instead of `first(Dates)` and `last(Dates)`, or `Dates[1L]` and `Dates[.N]`, resp., may lead to unexpected results with other datasets as `Dates` are given as character dates in the format `DD-MM-YYYY` which would be sorted on day of month, first.

### Data

```
df_Dates <- data.frame(
  Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
  Dates = c("01-01-2000", "02-01-2000", "03-01-2000", "01-05-2020", "02-05-2020", "03-05-2020"), 
  Departure = c("01-01-2000", "01-01-2000", "01-01-2000", NA, NA, NA), 
  Arrival = c(NA, NA, NA, "03-02-2020", "03-02-2020", "03-02-2020"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(Dates)[
  ,
  .(
    Dates = Dates,
    Departure = replace(Departure, is.na(Departure), min(Dates)),
    Arrival = replace(Arrival, is.na(Arrival), max(Dates))
  ),
  Group
]
```

gives

```
   Group      Dates  Departure    Arrival
1:     A 01-01-2000 01-01-2000 03-01-2000
2:     A 02-01-2000 01-01-2000 03-01-2000
3:     A 03-01-2000 01-01-2000 03-01-2000
4:     B 01-05-2020 01-05-2020 03-02-2020
5:     B 02-05-2020 01-05-2020 03-02-2020
6:     B 03-05-2020 01-05-2020 03-02-2020
```